# How do I subtract from one column if a specific condition is met in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three columns

| ID | Match_A | Match_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1 | 1 |
| DEF111 | 0 | 1 |
| QRS222 | 1 | 1 |

You can see ID 'ABC123' has a Match (as determined by 1) in both the Match_A and Match_B column. If their is a 1 in both of those columns, I am needing to write a formula that changes at least one of those columns into a 0. It doesn't matter if it's Match_A or Match_B.

The output for this ID would then turn into this.

| ID | Match_A | Match_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1 | 0 |

Essentially, a match can happen in both columns, but for this report managers do not want it to be counted twice so one column has to be changed to 0 if a situation like this happens.

Any help is appreciated here! Thank you!

Comment: Thats really quite a simple query, what did you try? Are you trying to make this to complicated??

Comment: both column of QRS222 is also same and it's 1 like ABC123.

Comment: Would you also consider the situation where Match_A = 0 and Match_B = 0 a ?Match? that needed changing

Comment: Not clear if you want a query to change the value in one of these columns (thats easy) or you want your report to treat one of these columns as if its not a 1 just for the purposes of producing the report

Comment: @riggsfolly If it's a 0 and 0 their needs to be no change. The only change needs to be if their is a 1 and 1

Comment: @RiggsFolly My query so far is simply SELECT unique_id, match_a, match_b from TABLE 1 and I am trying to manipulate it in Tableau. I am not entirely sure how you can subtract one column on the condition of another as I don't use SQL often.

Comment: @riggsfolly and yes, I'd like the value to change because my table has around 30,000 rows so I can't manually change it. I appreciate all the help.

I was thinking maybe an IF statement but that hasn't seemed to work.

Comment: Run this before the report `UPDATE table_name SET Match_B = 0 WHERE Match_A = 1 AND Match_B = 1;` See simple

Comment: @RiggsFolly It appears my permissions are locked when I try to do that. I'm a Junior Analyst who can only really do querying, and cannot update tables or manipulate them other than how the Data Engineer has them set.

Comment: Ok, so when I asked would you like to change these values in the db the answer should probably have been NO, I am not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a CASE should get you to the result I think you want

```
SELECT unique_id, match_a, 
        case when match_a = 1 AND match_a = match_b
            then 0
            else match_b 
        end as match_b
from table
```